# Google Colab - tensowflow object detection api - 'function' object has no attribute 'called'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I encountered the following error when I try to test the object detection api model_builder_test.py.

```
!apt-get install -y -qq protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml
!git clone --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

import os
os.chdir('models/research')

!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/models/research/slim')

%run object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

**The following error appears after running the model_builder_test.py**

> .W0220 03:22:35.097244 140099951081344 deprecation.py:323] From
>   /content/models/research/object_detection/anchor_generators/grid_anchor_generator.py:59:
>   to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will
>   be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use tf.cast
>   instead. .. WARNING: The TensorFlow contrib module will not be
>   included in TensorFlow 2.0. For more information, please see:   *
>   https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
>   * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.
>
> ..................s
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 22 tests in 0.203s
>
> OK (skipped=1)
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 get_ipython().magic('run object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py')
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py
>   in magic(self, arg_s)    2158         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s =
>   arg_s.partition(' ')    2159         magic_name =
>   magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
>   -> 2160         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)    2161     2162
>
> ## -------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py
>   in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)    2079
>   kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals    2080
>   with self.builtin_trap:
>   -> 2081                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)    2082             return result    2083
>
> in run(self, parameter_s, runner, file_finder)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in
>   (f, *a, **k)
>       186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
>       187     def magic_deco(arg):
>   --> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
>       189 
>       190         if callable(arg):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py
>   in run(self, parameter_s, runner, file_finder)
>       740                     else:
>       741                         # regular execution
>   --> 742                         run()
>       743 
>       744             if 'i' in opts:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/execution.py
>   in run()
>       726                         def run():
>       727                             runner(filename, prog_ns, prog_ns,
>   --> 728                                     exit_ignore=exit_ignore)
>       729 
>       730                     if 't' in opts:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in
>   mpl_execfile(fname, *where, **kw)
>       175         matplotlib.interactive(is_interactive)
>       176         # make rendering call now, if the user tried to do it
>   --> 177         if plt.draw_if_interactive.called:
>       178             plt.draw()
>       179             plt.draw_if_interactive.called = False
>
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'called'

Comment: Does this not come with a jupyter notebook?

Comment: I am using the jupyter notebook on colab...not sure what 'this' you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I overcame the issue:

1. install prompt-toolkit to the version 1.0.15, as explained in the link below
   https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/158
2. restart the runtime to activate the package
3. use '!python' instead of '%run'

Comment: It did not solve the problem in my case. I am still looking for ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Comment: @OsamaAdly You need to the PYTHONPATH env variable.

`import os`
`os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ":/content/models/research:/content/models/research/slim"`

Comment: This solved the error but the matplotlib plot doesn't display anymore :( Tried `! python3 pythonscript.py`, `!python pythonscript.py`, and `%run pythonscript.py`